# Is it possible to make hexagon of width=1 in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Here is what I got:

https://youtu.be/UwT-FbgqekI

Illustrator disobeys making hexagon of precise size.

Comment: Please note that computers operate on floating point numbers so even when a computer tells you something is say 0.1 it is most likely not true simply because you can not say 0.1 exactly in a  2 base representation (Phython docs explain this well, altough its a thing that applies to all floats  [See here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)).

Comment: Please include the relevant images in the question itself.